# How to enable chain extensions?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node

I have a chain extension implemented on [substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node) and in my [ink!](https://paritytech.github.io/ink-docs/) smart contract according to [this](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/v3.0.0-rc8/examples/rand-extension) tutorial. When I try to instantiate my contract on a local [contracts-ui](https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/) I get the following message:

```sh
module uses chain extensions but chain extensions are disabled
```

**What do I need to do to enable chain extensions?**

> [Here](https://github.com/brunopgalvao/chain-extension-example-001/commit/18f217af5813844b1f56b175d33eb9a6ebe7afa8) is my code for sanity check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have `type ChainExtension` defined in your runtime:

```rs
impl pallet_contracts::Config for Runtime {
    ....
    type ChainExtension = FetchRandomExtension;
}
```

...as indicated in the docs:

- https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/v3.0.0-rc8/examples/rand-extension#chain-side-integration

Also remember that there are two ways of running the [substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node):

1. Cloning it, modifying it, building it, running it:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node
cd substrate-contracts-node
cargo run --release -- --dev
```

> OR

2. Using `cargo install` and just running it:

```sh
cargo install contracts-node --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git --force --locked
substrate-contracts-node --dev
```

Turns out I was modifying my code and running my node using the second option (which was a completely different install!)